# How to insert Date and Time from script into PostgreSQL database while using java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, localdatetime

I'm having a problem with inserting Time correctly into the PostgreSQL database.
Making web app with SpringBoot, using JPARepository and hibernate.
Using this dialect:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

I have a class:

```
@Entity
public class Class {
//other stuff
@Column(name = "date_and_time")
private LocalDateTime dateAndTime;
```

I need some test data and when I start my app with this script:

```
insert into class(date_and_time) values (DATE('2020-06-10 18:43:20');
```

the result in my database looks like this
[2020-06-10 00:00:00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oioGw.png)

Is there any way I can insert time properly in my database?

Comment: Have you tried marking it as `@Temporal(TIMESTAMP)`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting your datetime to only date when you use the ‘DATE’ function, so you lose the time information. Simply remove the function and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. I found out just now that `('2020-06-10 18:43:20')::timestamp` also gets the job done.